# Function always returns none instead of printed statement

Tags: python, function, printing, nonetype

I am trying to create a rock, paper, scissors game in Python. I am a newbie so please forgive what may seem like a simple question. I am creating a function that can run through the user's choice and compare it to a random selection by the computer. I would like the results to be displayed as a print statement, however I keep getting None as the feedback. Please also note I know there are more potential outcomes, so far I am only testing the outcomes if the user selects "rock".

Here is the section of code:

```
import random

rkprsr = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

random.shuffle(rkprsr)

def gameplay (user_choice):
    dealer_choice = rkprsr.pop()
    if user_choice == 'rock' and dealer_choice == 'paper':
        print ('You selected rock and I selected paper. My paper covers your rock. You lose.')
    elif user_choice == 'rock' and dealer_choice == 'scissors':
        print ('You selected rock and I selected scissors. Your rock crushes my scissors. You win!')
    elif user_choice == 'rock' and dealer_choice == 'rock':
        print ('You selected rock and I selected rock. Stalemate. We tied.')
    return


user_choice = input ('Please type rock, paper, or scissors:')

print('')
print('')

user_choice = user_choice.lower

print (gameplay(user_choice))
```

Comment: `'print' != 'return'`, they're two completely different things.

Answer (score 2):

```
user_choice = user_choice.lower

print (gameplay(user_choice))
```

I see two problems. First, `lower` needs parentheses or else `user_choice` will be a function object rather than a string. This is why none of your `if` conditions are passing even though the user inputs "rock". Second, printing the result of `gameplay` will always print `None`, because that's what gets returned when you have a `return` statement with nothing after it. (or if you don't have a return statement at all).

```
user_choice = user_choice.lower()

gameplay(user_choice)
```

Comment: Great. I had removed the return statement during testing cycles and still got "None", the lower() was the missing key. Once I changed that and removed the empty return the program ran as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty `return` statement, which will return `None`. All printing is done within the function itself, so you don't need to print `gameplay(user_choice)`, nor do you need to have a `return` statement in the function. Simply call it and it should do what you expect. `None` is the return value from that function call so it is printed out.

Edit: As other poster noticed, `user_choice.lower` needs the parentheses to function properly

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to do the following:

```
def gameplay (user_choice):
    dealer_choice = rkprsr.pop()
    if user_choice == 'rock' and dealer_choice == 'paper':
        return 'You selected rock and I selected paper. My paper covers your rock. You lose.'
    elif user_choice == 'rock' and dealer_choice == 'scissors':
        return 'You selected rock and I selected scissors. Your rock crushes my scissors. You win!'
    elif user_choice == 'rock' and dealer_choice == 'rock':
        return 'You selected rock and I selected rock. Stalemate. We tied.'
```

The function `gameplay` will *return* a string, which you can print in the outer scope if you wish.